# Как проверить атрибуты перед созданием экземпляра?

Tags: python, классы

Есть класс:

```
class CarBase:
    def __init__(self, brand, photo_file_name, carrying):
        self.brand = brand
        self.photo_file_name = photo_file_name
        self.carrying = float(carrying)
```

Перед созданием экземпляра необходимо проверить `self.carrying` на тип `float` и `int`. И если атрибут не соответствует этим типам, то не создавать объект.

Можно ли сделать эту проверку в `__init__`, если да, как это сделать?

Comment: `if not isinstance(carrying, (int, float)): raise TypeError("что за фигню в carrying напихали")`

Answer (score 2):

я бы сделал это так:

```
class CarBase:
    def __init__(self, brand, photo_file_name, carrying):
        self.brand = brand
        self.photo_file_name = photo_file_name
        try:
            self.carrying = float(carrying) 
        except ValueError:
            raise TypeError(f"parameter `carrying` must be of either `int` or `float` type")
```

это более мягкая проверка по сравнению с `isinstance(carrying, (int, float))`, которая также позволит пользователю использовать строки, которые можно успешно сконвертировать во `float`

Comment: Только мне не нужны ошибки, мне надо, чтобы объект просто не создавался, тк чтение атрибутов идет из файла csv

Comment: @chernyahovsky2010, не совсем понимаю вас. Если вы напишете `c = aCarBase(1,2, "xxx")` - что должно быть в переменной `c`??

Comment: В переменной с должно быть число, либо целочисленное, либо с плавающей точкой

Comment: Если его там нет, то объект просто не должен быть создан

Comment: но идти по циклу чтения атрибутов дальше

Comment: @chernyahovsky2010, `"то объект просто не должен быть создан"` - по-моему, в  Python так сделать не получится)

Comment: Я могу сделать проверку в цикле чтения атрибутов из файлов, но можно ли сделать это в __init__?

Comment: @chernyahovsky2010, советую вам описать вашу задачу более широко / глобально. Как вы собираетесь использовать класс из вопроса?